# Insert into and run stored procedure with each select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO JETACE (TACE_KEY, TASK_KEY, CAET_KEY)
    SELECT @iTACE_KEY, TASK_KEY, CAET_KEY
    FROM JETACE
    WHERE TASK_KEY = @iTASK_KEY_CON
```

The only problem that I have is parameter `@iTACE_KEY` - it is unique (primary key) and generated like this:

```
EXEC @iTACE_KEY = sp_GETKEY 'JETACE', '0', '1', '9', @iUserId, @cTask='2'
```

I would like to run this sentence for each row in select statement, so each insertion will be combined from generated `@iTACE_KEY` and `TASK_KEY / CAET_KEY` taken from table `JETACE`. Is this possible?

Comment: Not with a proc. You could convert the proc into a function to use in your query, assuming the proc doesn't modify data.

Comment: Have you considered creating a function that holds the primary key generating code, which can be called in the select statement?

Comment: BTW, the stored procedure name prefix `sp_` should not be used for user procedures per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql).

Comment: Will `@iTACE_KEY` have the same value for all rows you are inserting? It appears so since you are passing constant values to `sp_GETKEY`. If its unique for each row, then please show the body of the stored procedure because it could be possible to incorporate that logic into your INSERT. ..SELECT statement.

Comment: @Sunil - No, value for iTACE_KEY is different. It is primary key, so it must be unique.

Comment: Ok. Is your stored procedure simply executing a SELECT using the parameters passed to it? Your best bet is to define the key logic in a user-defined scalar function as already suggested by others. Then, it's super easy to call the scalar-valued function in any query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with cursor:

```
DECLARE JETACE_01 cursor for
            SELECT CAET_KEY, TACE_SRT, TACE_STA
            FROM JETACE
            WHERE TASK_KEY = @iTASK_KEY_CON

            OPEN JETACE_01
            FETCH NEXT FROM JETACE_01 
            INTO @iCAET_KEY, @cTACE_SRT, @cTACE_STA


            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            begin

            EXEC @iTACE_KEY = sp_GETKEY 'JETACE', '0', '1', '9', @iUserId, @cTask='2'
            IF  (@@ERROR <> 0) OR (@iTACE_KEY < 0)
            BEGIN
                IF @cTask = '6'  
                    SELECT -61 TACE_KEY
                RETURN -61
            END

            INSERT INTO JETACE (TACE_KEY, TASK_KEY, CAET_KEY, TACE_SRT, TACE_STA, TACE_DAT, TACE_UAD, TACE_TAD)
            VALUES(@iTACE_KEY, @iTASK_KEY, @iCAET_KEY, @cTACE_SRT, @cTACE_STA, GETDATE(), @iUserId, GETDATE()) 


            FETCH NEXT FROM JETACE_01 
            INTO @iCAET_KEY, @cTACE_SRT, @cTACE_STA

            END


            CLOSE JETACE_01
            DEALLOCATE JETACE_01
```